# Get Chinese data form the clipboard with a parser in C#

Tags: c#

What DataFormat should I use if I have to parse the data in clipboard that contains Chinese?

Currently I'm using the following code to parse data from a `DataGrid`.

```
object clipboardRawData = null;
ParseFormat parseFormat = null;
IDataObject dataObj = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if ((clipboardRawData = dataObj.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) != null)
{
     parseFormat = ParseCsvFormat;
}
else if ((clipboardRawData = dataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Text)) != null)
{
      parseFormat = ParseTextFormat;
}
string rawDataStr = clipboardRawData as string;
```

`rawDataStr` returns gibberish if the clipboard data is in Chinese

Comment: Are you sure value is actually correct (i.e. you can past it to Word/Notepad and see valid text)?

Comment: Yeah. I tried with Excel. The data is valid.

Comment: Can u put the data copied on notepad here too... I mean the cell value which has issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `DataFormats.UnicodeText`. The `DataFormats.Text` will try to use ANSI encoding which will fail on Chinese symbols.

Comment: Oh, it won't fail per se. It just depends on the legacy codepage, which *could* be Chinese, I guess.